# How to use ObservableCollection in another ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection, itemscontrol

In my WPF app, I want to use an `ObservableCollection` to contain some `Wave` classes. Each `Wave` has an `ObservableCollection` to contain some `Couple` class. It looks like:

```
ObservableCollection<Wave> Waves { get; set; }
- int StartYear { get; set; }
- ObservableCollection<Couple> Couples { get; set; }
  - int A { get; set; }
  - int B { get; set; }
- some other Properties
```

After `Wave`s have been added, `int` properties work well. However, the `Couples` in every `Wave` changes when each of them has been changed. They have the same GUID.

How can `Couples`s in every `Wave` are different?

Here is my code:

```
// Couple.cs
public class Couple : DependencyObject
{
    public int A { get { return (int)GetValue(AProperty); } set { SetValue(AProperty, value); } }
    public int B { get { return (int)GetValue(BProperty); } set { SetValue(BProperty, value); } }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("A", typeof(int), typeof(Couple), new PropertyMetadata(0));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("B", typeof(int), typeof(Couple), new PropertyMetadata(0));
}
```

```
// Wave.cs
class Wave : DependencyObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<Couple> Couples
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Couple>)GetValue(CouplesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CouplesProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CouplesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Couples", typeof(ObservableCollection<Couple>), typeof(Wave), new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<Couple>()));
}
```

```
// XAML of the UserControl
<ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Waves}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Margin="0,0,0,6" Focusable="False" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Width="240">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Couples}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Text="01" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding A}"/>
                                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding B}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I am new to MVVM. Perviously, the values are got by use `Items` property of `ListBox`, but now I want to change these code to adapt to MVVM mode. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you set a non-null default value for a dependency property that is of a mutable reference type. All instances of the class that owns the property (i.e. all Wave objects) will use the same default collection object.

The constructor of the Wave class should set an initial value like

```
class Wave
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CouplesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(Couples),
            typeof(ObservableCollection<Couple>),
            typeof(Wave));

    public Wave()
    {
        Couples = new ObservableCollection<Couple>();
    }

    ...
}
```

---

Besides that, you should not derive your view model classes from DependencyObject. They should instead implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface if necessary:

```
public class Couple : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int a;

    public int A
    {
        get { return a; }
        set
        {
            a = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(A)));
        }
    }

    private int b;

    public int B
    {
        get { return b; }
        set
        {
            b = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(B)));
        }
    }
}

class Wave
{
    public ObservableCollection<Couple> Couples { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<Couple>();
}
```

Note that the `Couples` property is now read-only, and the owning class does hence not need to fire a change notification for that property.

---

For the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation you would typically have a base class that encapsulates the invokation of the PropertyChanged event, like

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected void SetValue<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName)
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
        {
            field = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
public class Couple : ViewModelBase
{
    private int a;

    public int A
    {
        get { return a; }
        set { SetValue(ref a, value, nameof(A)); }
    }

    private int b;

    public int B
    {
        get { return b; }
        set { SetValue(ref b, value, nameof(B)); }
    }
}
```